# R order lapply output from a function with multiple outputs by variable (column) rather than by function

Tags: r, lapply

I have a function in R which includes multiple other functions, including a custom one. I then use lapply to run the combined function across multiple variables. However, when the output is produced it is in the order of

function1: variable a, variable b, variable c

function2: variable a, variable b, variable c

When what I would like is for it to be the other way around:

variable a: function 1, function 2...

variable b: function 1, function 2...

I have recreated an example below using the mtcars dataset, with number of cylinders as a predictor variable, and vs and am as outcome variables.

```
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)
library(skimr)
library(car)

data(mtcars)

mtcars_binary <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(cyl, vs, am)


# logistic regression function
logistic.regression <- function(logmodel) {
  dev <- logmodel$deviance
  null.dev <- logmodel$null.deviance
  modelN <- length(logmodel$fitted.values)
  R.lemeshow <- 1 - dev / null.dev
  R.coxsnell <- 1 - exp ( -(null.dev - dev) / modelN)
  R.nagelkerke <- R.coxsnell / ( 1 - ( exp (-(null.dev / modelN))))
  cat("Logistic Regression\n")
  cat("Hosmer and Lemeshow R^2 ", round(R.lemeshow, 3), "\n")
  cat("Cox and Snell R^2 ",       round(R.coxsnell, 3), "\n")
  cat("Nagelkerke R^2" ,          round(R.nagelkerke, 3), "\n")
}

# all logistic regression results
log_regression_tests1 <- function(df_vars, df_data) {
  glm_summary <- glm(df_data[,df_vars] ~ df_data[,1], data = df_data, family = binomial, na.action = "na.omit")
  glm_print <- print(glm_summary)
  log_results <- logistic.regression(glm_summary)
  blr_coefficients <- exp(glm_summary$coefficients)
  blr_confint <- exp(confint(glm_summary))

  list(glm_summary = glm_summary, glm_print = glm_print, log_results = log_results, blr_coefficients = blr_coefficients, blr_confint = blr_confint)
}

log_regression_results1 <- sapply(colnames(mtcars_binary[,2:3]), log_regression_tests1, mtcars_binary, simplify = FALSE)
log_regression_results1
```

When I do this, the output is being produced as:

glm_summary: vs, am

log_results: vs, am

etc. etc.

When what I would like for the output to be ordered is:

vs: all function outputs

am: all function outputs

In addition, when I run this line of code, `log_regression_results1 <- sapply(colnames(mtcars_binary[,2:3]), log_regression_tests1, mtcars_binary, simplify = FALSE)` I get only the results of the logistic regression function, but when I print the overall results `log_regression_results1` I get the remaining output, could anyone explain why?

Finally, the glm_summary function is not producing all of the output which it should. When I run the functions independently on a single variable, like so

```
glm_vs <- glm(vs ~ cyl, data = mtcars_binary, family = binomial, na.action = "na.omit")
summary(glm_vs)

logistic.regression(glm_vs)

exp(glm_vs$vs)
exp(confint(glm_vs))
```

it also produces the standard error, z value, and p value for `summary(glm_vs)`  which it does not do embedded in the function, even though I have ```glm_print <- print(glm_summary)' included. Is there a way to get the output for the full summary function within the log_regression_tests1 function?

Answer (score 0):

when I run your code up to `log_regression_results1` I got exactly what you ask for:
`summary(log_regression_results1)
   Length Class  Mode
vs 5      -none- list
am 5      -none- list`

maybe you meant to ask the other way round?

Comment: what I am looking for is the results of all the tests, in the order of the variables. At the moment it seems to be printing only the glm_summary and log_results output when I run `log_regression_results1 <- sapply(colnames(mtcars_binary[,2:3]), log_regression_tests1, mtcars_binary, simplify = FALSE)`, then the rest of the output when I run `log_regression_results1`, I was hoping to be able to combine them. In addition, the glm_summary output is incomplete compared to running the code for a single variable (does not produce the standard error, z value, and p-value)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer then